# How to keep terraform's state correct when change state file path?

Tags: terraform

In the version.tf file, stored key in AWS S3 before

```
terraform {
  required_version = "1.0.10"

  ...

  backend "s3" {
    encrypt        = true
    bucket         = "terraform-bucket"
    key            = "project1/api/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = "state-lock"
  }
}
```

It's in this path

```
project1/api/
```

If change the `api` folder to `price-api`, also adjust the state key path:

```
    key            = "project1/price-api/terraform.tfstate"
```

It will create new resources beside the previous state key. How to avoid the duplicated state occurred if change key name in the version.tf? Or is there a way to sync the state file with S3 file to ensure they are the same status?

Comment: Have you tried copying the old state file to the new file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`terraform init` includes some extra functionality to help with migration of your state between two storage locations.

To use it, you must first initialize your working directory with the *old* configuration, using the current object key where your state snapshot exists today. Run `terraform init` with no options to activate that, if you haven't already. (If you're working in a directory you've previously used for other operations then it may already be initialized; you could ensure a clean situation by deleting the `.terraform` subdirectory and everything inside it.)

Once you've seen `terraform init` complete successfully with the original path, run `terraform show` to see if Terraform returns the infrastructure you're expecting to see. This will help confirm that you did indeed select the correct current location for the state you want to migrate.

Now, in the same working directory, change your `backend "s3"` block to include the new path. If you run `terraform init` now then Terraform will notice that you changed the backend configuration and will ask you to decide between migrating your state or "reconfiguring".

Migrating state here means to have Terraform read the current state snapshot from the old location, and then write it immediately to the new location, and then initialize from there. That matches what you described in your question, so you can choose that option by running `terraform init -migrate-state`, as mentioned in the prompt from the previous run.

After you do this you may have the same state snapshot in both locations, so I'd recommend to look directly into the corresponding S3 bucket (using normal S3 tools, rather than Terraform) and check to make sure that the new object is present and matches the old one. If so, you can then safely manually delete the old one just to avoid confusion for anyone who might try to work with an older version of your configuration which still refers to the old path.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's good to do with terraform but maybe difficult with [atlantis](https://www.runatlantis.io/).

Comment: Indeed, Atlantis is good for "routine" operations (which you will configure once and then run many times) but it's not ideal for occasional maintenance like this. I would suggest doing the state migration with Terraform CLI directly, outside of Atlantis, and then you can go back to using Atlantis once your codebase and S3 bucket both agree on where the state is now stored.

Comment: Yes, it seems a good way to do the migration. Thank you for the good suggestion.